# Does Oracle NoSQL support Open JDK?

Tags: oracle-nosql

Is OpenJDK supported ? In the release notes, it is indicated that Oracle NoSQL database suppport open JDK but when I try to install, I have the following error :

```
21.1.12 2021-04-08 06:19:55 UTC  Build id: f48d499c8588 
Edition: Client
N/A JDK is not supported. 
Please use a Java version equal to or newer than the
following recommended versions: Private Build 
Java 1.8.0, Azul Systems, Inc. Java 1.8.0, 
IBM Corporation Java 1.7.0, 
Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0
```

```
[opc@node1-nosql script]$ java -version
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 19.9 (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.9 (build 13.0.2+8, 
mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I realized that it was working with the open JDK downloaded from https://jdk.java.net/archive/

I opened a ticket and Oracle is working to solve this. It was happening when installing  Red Hat JDK.

```
java -XshowSettings:properties 2>&1 | grep vendor
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor = Red Hat, Inc.
    java.vendor.url = https://www.redhat.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug =
    java.vendor.version = 20.3
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.vendor = Red Hat, Inc.
```

I followed the recommendation in the error message about the recommended version and it is working now using open JDK.

```
Please use a Java version equal to or newer than the
following recommended versions: Private Build 
Java 1.8.0, Azul Systems, Inc. Java 1.8.0, 
IBM Corporation Java 1.7.0, 
Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0
```